# WPF: Can a Visual contain children?

Tags: c#, wpf

The presence of an [AddVisualChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.addvisualchild.aspx) method seems to imply that one can add a child visual to an object derived from `Visual`. If so, what is the purpose of the [ContainerVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.containervisual.aspx)`class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most `Visual` derived classes allows for a single parent-child relationship in terms of visuals.  By putting [AddVisualChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.addvisualchild.aspx) within the Visual class, all Visual derived classes that allow for a child or children can use the same methodology and logic to manage their parent relationships.

`ContainerVisual` is intended for `Visual` implementations that allow for *multiple children*, via the [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.containervisual.children.aspx) property.

`Visual`, on the other hand, provides the plumbing to allow subclasses to expose a single child (`Content`), no content, or multiple Children using a uniform API.